# No module named 'scipy', although installed with Anaconda. Python 3 on Windows 10

Tags: scipy, python-3.6

I did conda install for numpy, pandas, scipy, and scikit-learn apparently all successful. I also tried to change the path in the Windows 10 registry. I only have 1 version of Python, 3.6 installed. I also installed Visual Studio. If I run the script, I get "scipy module not found". Can you explain me what's the problem, and how to fix this?

My imports look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl, math
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation, svm
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

I'm following this tutorial by Sentdex:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4mwkS2T9aI&index=4&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfKTOs3Keq_kaG2P55YRn5v

Comment: What statement you have used to import scipy.    ? Mention all the things in your question.

Comment: Yes, I should have done this.

Comment: Then edit you question Let us try to answer